# Stuck in a loop problem, cannot figure out the solution

Tags: solidity, smart-contract

I am suppose to write a funciton that takes row,col and values and return a list within a list such that for example, row=3 , col=4 , value=9 , it should give out **[ [9,9,9,9] , [9,9,9,9] ,[9,9,9,9] ]** , I have written this function but I am not able to find out why it is not working. It says, 'push function not found after argument dependent look up for uint8.

```
contract HelloWorld{
    uint8[][] grid;

    function makegrid(uint8 row, uint8 col,uint8 value) public returns(uint[][] memory){
        for (uint8 i;i<=row;i++){
            for (uint8 j;j<=col;j++){
                grid[i][j].push(value);
            }
        }
        return grid;

    }   

}
```

Help me please and explain too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, In the Solidity for-loop examples I saw, they initialized the counter varaible to zero.  Try setting `i` and `j` to `0`.

Comment: I did, the error did not go away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
contract HelloWorld{
    uint8[][] public grid;

    function makegrid(uint8 row, uint8 col,uint8 value) public {
        for (uint8 i;i<row;i++){
            uint8[] memory temp = new uint8[](col);
            for (uint8 j;j<col;j++){
                temp[j] = value;
            }
            grid.push(temp);
        }
    }   
}
```

Memory dynamic arrays don't have push, only storage. This way you create each row in temp, then push it to the grid.

Hope this makes sense.